# Hibernate Search issues on VMWare ESXi?

Tags: jenkins, vmware, hibernate-search, esxi

I'm running integration tests in a Jenkins build environment, installed on VMWARE ESXi 4.0.0. Everything went well until I've included Hibernate Search into the application. From then on entities were reported missing during the integration tests. For example:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.foo.model.Bar with id 538.
```

I'm suspecting an impact from VMWare's ESXi because:

1. It runs fine locally.
2. I had a similar case already( [EhCache + Hibernate Cache is not alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646651/ehcache-hibernate-cache-is-not-alive) ) where it's very likely ESXi is causing the problem. That one could be worked around. This problem however can not.

I've been trying a lot of workarounds but it's always the same problem. Unless I disable Hibernate Search. But then the search integration tests fail. :-)

Is there anybody in here who has a hint about a possible fix ? Or at least an explanation as to why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is the same problem as [EhCache + Hibernate Cache is not alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646651/ehcache-hibernate-cache-is-not-alive). Because there's no error when switching off the 2nd level cache.

This happens even for Hibernate 4.1.1-Final.

Copying the ESXi VM to a local VMplayer causes the same error. So I might deduce ASXi specifically is not the cause. But rather VMWare VM's.